# How to add table to document comment in Swift 4?

Tags: comments, swift4, document

hHow to add **table** to **document comment** in Swift 4?

Like iOS `NSString.appendingPathExtension` document. See attach image:

[image]

I see Apple's [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html), but I have not found comment grammar about creating **table**. How do I do this?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that an image? like a png or jpg file

Comment: @E.Coms  You mean the **Table** is a picture actually???

Comment: Maybe or maybe not. But you know how to insert an image.

Comment: @E.Coms it's not a image. I update my question。 the **table** can **stretch**, is flexible。

Comment: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet。 this may help

Comment: @E.Coms it's not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Markdown table formate.

```
    /// | Sloth speed  | Description                           |
    /// | ------------ | ------------------------------------- |
    /// | `slow`       | Moves slightly faster than a snail.   |
    /// | `medium`     | Moves at an average speed.            |
    /// | `fast`       | Moves faster than a hare.             |
    /// | `supersonic` | Moves faster than the speed of sound. |
```

see more at [Formatting your documentation content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/formatting-your-documentation-content)